# PHP writable issue with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions

After changing the file permissions to allow a picture upload I am now getting Internal Server Error and none of the following code is having a chance to execute. This all happened when I changed the file permissions of the folder /upload.

THE PHP

```
<?php

$filename = 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/admin/upload/test.gif';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}

print_r($_FILES);
if ($_FILES['thumbfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $info = getimagesize($_FILES['thumbfile']['tmp_name']);
    if (($info[2] !== IMG_GIF) && ($info[2] !== IMG_JPEG)) {
       die("not a gif/jpg");
    }
    if (filesize($_FILES['thumbfile']['tmp_name']) > 20000) {
       die("larger than 20000");
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumbfile']['tmp_name'], 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/admin/upload/test.jpg');

      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
parent.document.getElementById("thumbprogress").innerHTML = "Archiving"</script>Archiving';

  }
else
  {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
parent.document.getElementById("thumbprogress").innerHTML = "Invalid File Format"</script>Invalid File Format';
  }
?>
```

Currently the file permissions of the upload folder are open to all as writable.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Marvellous

Comment: Do NOT make files world writable. You WILL get hacked.

Comment: The webserver's error log will contain details as to what triggered the 500 error. Generally it'll be a bad .htaccess file, as it's rare for PHP to blow up so badly it can't spit out a PHP error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upload to a local folder, not to an internet URL, ej:

$filename = '/var/www/my-site/z-images/admin/upload/test.gif';

Comment: clarify slightly. Should it be /var/www/divethegap.com/update/z-images/admin/upload/test.gif ???

Comment: It should be whatever is the path to your file. You can use $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] to get a hint of what paths you are working in.